# Is it possible to use a Hashtable in this instance?

Tags: java, heap, hashtable, priority-queue

So I have a separate min and max PriorityQueues and need a way to coordinate them.  I have song objects that each have 3 ints tied with them.  Is there a way to coordinate the "heaps" in the Priority Queues using hashtable?  For example, here is my song constructor

```
public Song(int name, int N, int L) {
    this.name = name;
    . . .
}
```

Later on, when I am inserting into the PriorityQueues, I want to associate the value in the min and max queues to the value p, defined by...

```
P = N+2L
```

So for example, when creating and adding a value I would say

```
public SongCollection() {
    max = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(500, Collections.reverseOrder());
    min = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(500);
    hash = new Hashtable<Song,Integer>();
}

addSong(int date) {
    Song song = new Song(date, 20, 20);
    hash.put(song, song.getP());
    max.add(song.getP());
    min.add(song.getP());
}
```

Later on, I would like to update the "N" and "L" values of my song by modifying the song object that relates to the one I want to modify.

Is this the correct way to set this up?  Could I later recall the lowest value in my min heap, restore its song object, then delete the object and the two instances in my heaps?

Comment: Both of your custom comparators just implement natural order, and so are unnecessary; also, you could write the same as `return lhs.compareTo(rhs)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks, I have corrected it.

Comment: Behavior of `PriorityQueue` is not specified if you change the sort order of objects that already are in the queue.  Remove the object from both queues first, then modify it, and then put it back into both queues.

Comment: @jameslarge I have done that as well, thank you.  Now the question is, how do I look up a certain Song object with its P value?  Say I want to remove the lowest P value from the Queues, I find the lowest in min, then relate that to the hashtable (somehow), then remove it from max as well.

Comment: Wait, why `PriorityQueue<Integer>`?  Why not `PriorityQueue<Song>`?  And what is the purpose of the hash table?  If you have a Song, you can call song.getP(), so why would you need to look up P in a hash?

Comment: The reason it's `PriorityQueue<Integer>` is because I'm sorting the queues by song.getP().  Having queues with Songs wouldn't sort them the way I'm wanting them to be sorted.  I'm using a hashtable so that I can cross reference between the two queues.  When I change the N or L values, I will need to find the value that coorelates with the song in the min and max queues (using hashtable Enumeration), and remove them, then alter them, then replace them back in the queues.